# MATLAB R2015b 64bit Installation Problem

Tags: software-installation, java, matlab

I am having a problem while installing MATLAB R2015b.
I have downloaded the .iso file, copied all the files in `/home/user/R2015b_glnxa64`. Now when I run `sudo ./install` in that directory, I receive this error:

> /home/user/R2015b_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: 1: /home/user/R2015b_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

I have checked the md5 checksum and it seems there is no problem with the iso file.
`java -version` output is:

> java version "1.8.0_60"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

I have also ran `chmod -R +x` on the directory. What seems to be the problem?

EDIT : hexdump output:

> 0000000000 |67.k..._..$..E~||
>
> 0000000016 |.T.a..J.(.S.p3.>|
>
> 0000000032 |../....y|

EDIT: Added the solution as an answer.

Comment: this is not Ubuntu error, but MATLAB itself. out-of-scope.

Comment: @AizuddinZali Your statement is false. Other people have installed it from the same iso file. This has only happened to me.

Comment: this is not standard Ubuntu software, unless you having issue with Ubuntu component or packages then it will be in-scope.  Syntax error is what it says, there are syntax should not be there or incomplete.

Comment: so have you inspect install_unix? make it verbose? is install_unix contains java execution line?

Comment: @AizuddinZali install_unix is a binary file.

Comment: which binary file type? C? java?

Comment: @A.B. `install_unix: data`

Comment: @A.B. hexdump: ""%010_ad |" 16/1 "%_p" "|\n" /home/user/R2015b_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64/install_unix": bad format

Comment: @A.B. Added the hexdump output.

Comment: Are the installation you downloaded is for ubuntu and linux?

Comment: @A.B this is out of scope and shall be flagged.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to install this on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: @steeldriver uname -m output: `x86_64`

Comment: Write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a problem with the way the ISO file was mounted. used `mount` instead of `fuseiso` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

use osirrox to extract iso

```
osirrox -indev /path/to/iso -extract / /full-iso-contents
```